# js decorator arguments.callee.name is empty

Tags: javascript, decorator

```
class Decorators {
    static PubSub(middleware) {
        let decoratorName = arguments.callee.name
        return function(target, key, descriptor) {
        }
    }
}

let PubSub = Decorators.PubSub

class User {
    @PubSub(null)
    static users() {}
}
```

I expected decoratorName to be PubSub but it is an empty string

Comment: Are you using a transpiler? What environment are you executing this code in?

Comment: You should not use `class` syntax when you have only static methods - use a plain object literal!